# Сломался вход в Xfce в Ubuntu (Xubuntu)

Tags: linux, xfce

Xfce в Ubuntu после upgrade VirtualBox на Windows 7 перестал запускаться из Xlogin. Unity и т.п. работают.

На самом деле выбор сессии Xfce запускается, но он как бы скрыт заставкой от login(?) (пустой экран пурпурного цвета) которая не исчезает. Когда закрываю машину, то видно окно Xfce с выбором сессии.

Попробовал поставить Mate и абсолютно та же картина. В него тоже не могу войти, а когда машину перезапускаешь, то видна стартовая картинка Mate.

Не могу найти в сети, какие конфиги и как надо поредактировать.

P.S.

Все относящееся к Xfce в системе установлено

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for avp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (2.225).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
avp@avp-ubu1:~$
```

(по крайней мере она сама так считает)

*** Update 1 *** (на комментарий 1)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ update-alternatives --display x-window-manager; update-alternatives --display x-session-manager
x-window-manager - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/metacity
  link currently points to /usr/bin/metacity
  link x-window-manager is /usr/bin/x-window-manager
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-window-manager.1.gz
/usr/bin/marco - priority 30
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/marco.1.gz
/usr/bin/metacity - priority 60
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/metacity.1.gz
/usr/bin/mutter - priority 60
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mutter.1.gz
/usr/bin/xfwm4 - priority 60
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/xfwm4.1.gz
x-session-manager - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/gnome-session
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gnome-session
  link x-session-manager is /usr/bin/x-session-manager
  slave x-session-manager.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-session-manager.1.gz
/usr/bin/gnome-session - priority 50
  slave x-session-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-session.1.gz
/usr/bin/mate-session - priority 50
  slave x-session-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mate-session.1.gz
/usr/bin/startxfce4 - priority 50
  slave x-session-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/startxfce4.1.gz
/usr/bin/xfce4-session - priority 40
  slave x-session-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/xfce4-session.1.gz
avp@avp-ubu1:~$
```

*** Update 2 ***

Игрался с дефолтными DM (gdm3/lightdm) -- без результата.
Снес и переставил `xubuntu-desktop` -- все так же уныло.

Что может мешать запустившемуся (из под `gdm3`)  xfce4-session  скрипту Xfce показывать картинку на экране?

И 2 экземпляра `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth ...` и `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth ...` (один от *gdm*, а другой *avp*) что-то мне не нравятся (хотя, скорее всего это так и задумано, но не мешает ли что-то их синхронной работе?)

Comment: приложите вывод `$ update-alternatives --display x-window-manager; update-alternatives --display x-session-manager`

Comment: попробуйте сменить альтернативы на подходящие к xfce по смыслу: x-window-manager установите на /usr/bin/xfwm4, а x-session-manager — на /usr/bin/startxfce4 или /usr/bin/xfce4-session (`$ sudo update-alternatives --config имя`)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, сейчас попробую перелогиниться

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, перелогиниться не помогло, хотя поведение изменилось (теперь не висит, а тут же возвращается в login)/ Пробую перегрузиться

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, перезагрузка не помогла. Но тут же в login не возвращается. Приходится перезапускать машину. Unity работает.  Очевидно, какая-то ерунда с login/ Придется изучать процесс запуска (это systemd?)

Comment: смотрите логи (в `/var/log/чего-то-там` и в файле `~/.xsession-errors`)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93660/discussion-between-avp-and-aleksandr-barakin).

Comment: @avp, может Вам на [superuser](https://superuser.com/) или [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) вопрос продублировать? На практике решения там быстрее находятся. А после можно и сюда ответ запостить.

Comment: @МихаилРебров,  считаете что **практического смысла** в нашем сайте нет? Или  вы носитель английского? Я нет, мне на нем общаться не комфортно.

Comment: @avp, если бы я считал что в нашем сайте нет смысла, то меня бы здесь не было. Просто мне кажется, что когда перед тобой стоит реальная техническая задача, то тут особо не до выбора..порой и на китайском и японском приходится искать. Я никого с порогу на enSO на спроваживаю, просто видел что Вы неоднократно подымали данный вопрос и так и не получили ответа... В свою очередь у меня есть позитивный опыт работы с юникс сообществами SE... они профильные простая вероятность получения ответа там будет выше. К тому же я сразу же предложил Вам запостить найденный ответ, на благо нашему сообществу.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо обновлять софт на старом железе.

Повозившись с новой виртуалкой и установкой свежескачанного образа Xubuntu я понял, что просто `Xfce` в `Linux 4.15.0-48-generic Ubuntu SMP под VirtualBox 5.2.28/30` в 7-й винде не совместим с
**3-D ускорением** (по крайней мере у меня с `Palit 1024Mb GF GTS 450 (GDDR5) DVI, HDMI, VGA , NE5S4500F0601/HD01-N1062`)

Вот и все.
Выключил 3-D acceleration и все опять заработало.